# How to web scrape a list of URLs of a website with multiprocessing when I login using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

First of all I am a beginner with Python. Now I am trying to create a script that does the following

1. login to a website using Selenium
2. load a list of the website's URLs from a CSV file
3. web scrape data using multiprocessing method

I am using the following script

```
#Load URLS from CSV
def mycontents():
    contents = []
    with open('global_csv.csv', 'r') as csvf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            contents.append(row[1]) # Add each url to list contents
    return contents
# parse a single item to get information
def parse(url):   

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}  

r = requests.get(url, headers, timeout=10)
sleep(3)

info = []
availability_text = '-'
price_text = '-'


if r.status_code == 200:
    print('Processing..'+ url)
    html = r.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(4)
    price = soup.select(".price")
          
    if price is not None:
     price_text = price.text.strip()
     print(price_text)
    else:
     price_text = "0,00"
     print(price_text)

    availability = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'wholesale-availability'})
    
    if availability is not None:
     availability_text = availability.text.strip()
     print(availability_text)
    else:
     availability_text = "Not Available"
     print(availability_text)

    info.append(price_text)
    info.append(availability_text)        

return ';'.join(info)

web_links = None
web_links = mycontents()

#Insert First Row
fields=['SKU','price','availability']
with open('output_global.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Load Webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get('TheLoginPage')
    #Find Username Field
    username = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
    username.send_keys('myusername')
    #Find Password Field
    password = browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
    time.sleep(2)
    password.send_keys('mypassword')
    #Find Connect Button
    sing_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="send2"]')
    sing_in.click()
    #Start MultiProcess
    with Pool(4) as p:    
      records = p.map(parse, web_links)

    if len(records) > 0:
         with open('output_global.csv', 'a') as f:
          f.write('\n'.join(records))
```

When I run the script is not getting anything and in Command Window it is just shows the URLs, which makes me think that even if I connect successfully the sessions are different?!

I tried to save the session by putting it inside parse method or

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

I tried to connect to the browser the same session but I get errors like

1. You have not defined a session
2. TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
3. local variable 'session' referenced before assignment

How can I practically login to the website and **use multiprocessing** to web scrape the URLs I need?

Comment: your indenting is off

Comment: I did copy paste :) nevertheless can you help?